# btrfs balance kernel bug?

Tags: kernel, btrfs

After getting a little annoyed with no space left errors when deleting files
I started a btrfs balance process and 2-3 times the following appeared.
Is this serious for my data or can I just ignore it because there is a security measure that handles even such errors ?

**edit:** Reported the bug at [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1130539)

```
[  693.130413] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  693.130509] kernel BUG at /build/buildd/linux-3.5.0/fs/btrfs/relocation.c:2278!
[  693.130645] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP
[  693.130744] CPU 0
[  693.130787] Modules linked in: sp5100_tco kvm_amd kvm psmouse k10temp serio_raw i2c_piix4 radeon ext2 ttm drm_kms_helper drm i2c_algo_bit mac_hid lp parport btrfs zlib_deflate libcrc32c hid_generic usbhid hid pata_atiixp r8169 microcode
[  693.131415]
[  693.131430] Pid: 2384, comm: btrfs Tainted: G        W    3.5.0-23-generic #35-Ubuntu To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./E350M1
[  693.131678] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa00da3e2>]  [<ffffffffa00da3e2>] merge_reloc_roots+0x142/0x150 [btrfs]
[  693.131901] RSP: 0018:ffff88012315da58  EFLAGS: 00010286
[  693.132004] RAX: 00000000ffffffe2 RBX: ffff88004ef5f000 RCX: 00000000ffffffe2
[  693.132137] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffffffa00ef050 RDI: ffff880138f04000
[  693.132270] RBP: ffff88012315da88 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff88013ec1b660
[  693.132402] R10: ffffffffa006aaea R11: ffffffffa007e900 R12: ffff880134ce6000
[  693.132535] R13: ffff88012315da58 R14: ffff880134ce6590 R15: ffff880134ce6000
[  693.132669] FS:  00007f904729e740(0000) GS:ffff88013ec00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  693.132818] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[  693.132927] CR2: 00007f3f2ce4c050 CR3: 00000001286a2000 CR4: 00000000000007f0
[  693.133059] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  693.133193] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  693.133326] Process btrfs (pid: 2384, threadinfo ffff88012315c000, task ffff8801391ac500)
[  693.133474] Stack:
[  693.133519]  ffff88012315da58 ffff88012315da58 00000000ffffffe2 ffff880134ce6020
[  693.133689]  ffff880134ce60e8 ffff88012e424510 ffff88012315db18 ffffffffa00da89d
[  693.133859]  ffff88012315db18 ffff88012315dae0 0000000000000001 00000000ffffffe4
[  693.134029] Call Trace:
[  693.134127]  [<ffffffffa00da89d>] relocate_block_group+0x26d/0x690 [btrfs]
[  693.134300]  [<ffffffffa00dae6f>] btrfs_relocate_block_group+0x1af/0x2e0 [btrfs]
[  693.134482]  [<ffffffffa00b7165>] btrfs_relocate_chunk.isra.53+0x75/0x720 [btrfs]
[  693.134663]  [<ffffffffa00c60d8>] ? btrfs_set_lock_blocking_rw+0xa8/0xf0 [btrfs]
[  693.134809]  [<ffffffff81082203>] ? __wake_up+0x53/0x70
[  693.134953]  [<ffffffffa00aedc9>] ? release_extent_buffer.isra.38+0x79/0xe0 [btrfs]
[  693.135138]  [<ffffffffa00b3f07>] ? free_extent_buffer+0x37/0x90 [btrfs]
[  693.135306]  [<ffffffffa00bb397>] __btrfs_balance+0x427/0x7f0 [btrfs]
[  693.135470]  [<ffffffffa00bbad4>] btrfs_balance+0x374/0x550 [btrfs]
[  693.135630]  [<ffffffffa00c02d4>] btrfs_ioctl_balance+0x124/0x460 [btrfs]
[  693.135765]  [<ffffffff816838de>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0xe/0x20
[  693.135913]  [<ffffffffa00c55b9>] btrfs_ioctl+0x1049/0x12d0 [btrfs]
[  693.136039]  [<ffffffff8114b1d9>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x259/0x320
[  693.136158]  [<ffffffff8132f960>] ? rb_insert_color+0x110/0x150
[  693.136276]  [<ffffffff8168754c>] ? do_page_fault+0x1cc/0x4e0
[  693.136392]  [<ffffffff8114eb5f>] ? vma_link+0xcf/0xe0
[  693.136497]  [<ffffffff81193d19>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x99/0x590
[  693.136607]  [<ffffffff8116df80>] ? kmem_cache_free+0x20/0x100
[  693.136723]  [<ffffffff811942a9>] sys_ioctl+0x99/0xa0
[  693.136828]  [<ffffffff8168bb69>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[  693.136941] Code: f9 ff ff 85 c0 74 97 0f 0b 85 d2 0f 85 08 ff ff ff 49 83 bc 24 80 05 00 00 00 75 15 48 83 c4 10 31 c0 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 <0f> 0b 0f 0b 0f 0b 0f 0b 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 57 41
[  693.137853] RIP  [<ffffffffa00da3e2>] merge_reloc_roots+0x142/0x150 [btrfs]
[  693.138034]  RSP <ffff88012315da58>
[  693.138146] ---[ end trace 9311971051c0a78e ]---
```

Comment: Is BTRFS even production ready?

Comment: NO its not production ready....

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the kernel, which should be reported to your distribution with full details.

BTRFS is still a few years away from being solid enough to rely on it for serious use. For personal use, for experiments, wherever data is safe elsewhere or not critical, knock yourself out. For use in *real* anger, the default is ext3/ext4.

Comment: Yes, I'm glad that I started to test it with non critical data. Bug is reported. Thanks.